# Using the_post_thumbnail do not rollback to original image if specified thumbnail does not exist

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

We have a series of posts some do not have a defined thumbnail size (i.e. **"small-featured"**). Right now with `the_post_thumbnail()` if WordPress can not find that size it replaces it with the original size in a listing page we created.

Is it possible to request that if that exact size does not exist don't display an image instead of forcing a massive original image?

Thanks.

Comment: Can You provide the code snippet of your theme template where You call `the_post_thumbnail()`, cause if function not find the image, it must return null(empty) `' '`. Looks like this modified by theme filters or etc. Also You can try to set the size of thumb. with first param `thumbnail`, `medium`, `large`, `full`.

Comment: You could use the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin, which can go through your whole media library and add those missing sizes. As long as all of your desired image sizes are still set up, it will generate each size for each file.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine problem is we have well over 400K - 500K images

Comment: It runs on any number of images.